# creating with a belongs_to has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the error `unknown attribute: user_id` durring execution of `@user.posts.create` in my specs

User Class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # new columns need to be added here to be writable through mass assignment
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Post Class

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body

  belongs_to :user
end
```

DB Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111214045425) do

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Any help? I've followed every guide I can find for using ActiveRecord. All I want to do is create a Post with an associated User.

Comment: try changing to <b>has_many :posts, class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "user_id", :dependent => "destroy"</b> and <b>belongs_to :user, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "user_id"</b>. Sometimes ActiveRecord can be a bit wonky. Don't forget to restart server

Comment: Are you sure the the column `user_id` exists in your `posts` table?

Comment: The DB Schema is what I got from rake `rake db:schema:dump`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@user = User.find(1)
@post = @user.posts.build(posts_attributes_as_hash)
@post.save
```

Or even

```
post = Post.new(posts_attributes)
@user = User.find(1)
@user.posts << post
```

Edit

To use create directly:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@post = @user.posts.create(posts_attributes_as_hash)
```

For more information have a look at [has_many-association-reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) especially at section called `4.3.1 Methods Added by has_many`

New Edit:

I created a new project with your code and in rails console I tried the following commands

```
User.create(:username => "UserNamedTest", :email => "usernamedtest@somewhere.com")

SQL (13.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "password_hash", "password_salt", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 14 Dec 2011 09:02:46 UTC +00:00], ["email", "usernamedtest@somewhere.com"], ["password_hash", nil], ["password_salt", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 14 Dec 2011 01:03:26 UTC +00:00], ["username", "UserNamedTest"]]

=> #<User id: 2, username: "UserNamedTest", email: "usernamedtest@somewhere.com", password_hash: nil, password_salt: nil, created_at: "2011-12-14 09:02:46", updated_at: "2011-12-14 09:02:46">

user =  User.find_by_username("UserNamedTest")

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'UserNamedTest' LIMIT 1

=> #<User id: 2, username: "UserNamedTest", email: "usernamedtest@somewhere.com", password_hash: nil, password_salt: nil, created_at: "2011-12-14 09:02:46", updated_at: "2011-12-14 09:02:46">

new_post = user.posts.create(:title => "just a test", :body =>"body of article test")

SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("body", "created_at", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "body of article test"], ["created_at", Wed, 14 Dec 2011 09:03:59 UTC +00:00], ["title", "just a test"], ["updated_at", Wed, 14 Dec 2011 09:03:59 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2]]

=> #<Post id: 2, title: "just a test", body: "body of article test", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-12-14 09:03:59", updated_at: "2011-12-14 09:03:59">

irb(main):022:0> new_post.inspect
=> "#<Post id: 2, title: \"just a test\", body: \"body of article test\", user_id: 2, created_at: \"2011-12-14 09:03:59\", updated_at: \"2011-12-14 09:03:59\">"
```

From what I see the code is ok, the post get created with no errors

Comment: sorry for that, I edited the example with build to reflect that build returns a new post

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to why he is getting the error. You're basically suggesting different ways of doing what he is already doing. And now as a last suggestion you suggest doing EXACTLY the same thing he is already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue after a dump of the test.sqlite3 schema. `user_id` was not defined as a column in the db. Blowing out the database and running `rake spec` migrates the database and fixes everything.